# Recursive Manipulation of Employee and Supervisor Data to Produce Org Tree Hierarchy in R

Tags: r

I commonly analyze data in an "org tree" format to understand the frequency of activities under a given leader within the organization. I need to produce a wide hierarchy from two columns of data: employee name and supervisor name.

```
----------
df <- data.frame("Employee"=c("Bill","James","Amy","Jen","Henry"),
                      "Supervisor"=c("Jen","Jen","Steve","Amy","Amy"))
df
#   Employee Supervisor
# 1     Bill        Jen
# 2    James        Jen
# 3      Amy      Steve
# 4      Jen        Amy
# 5    Henry        Amy
```

End with a wide data frame that specifies the org chart, starting with the CEO (or the topmost employee):

```
#  Employee       H1     H2    H3
# 1    Bill    Steve    Amy   Jen
# 2   James    Steve    Amy   Jen
# 3     Amy    Steve     NA    NA
# 4     Jen    Steve    Amy    NA
# 5   Henry    Steve    Amy    NA
```

After much research, the `data.tree` package seems to offer the most help. How can I perform this operation?

Comment: You can make a tree with `data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork(df)`. Are you sure you really want the columns like that in the final output? What do you plan to do with the data afterward?

Comment: I am flexible with the final output. What do you recommend? I need a way to filter by a given leader (e.g. Amy) and change the data to represent that leader's workforce (anyone who eventually rolls up to the leader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

setnames(df, 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor.1')

j=1
while (df[, any(get(paste0('Supervisor.',j)) %in% Employee)]) {
  df[df, on=paste0('Supervisor.',j,'==Employee'),
     paste0('Supervisor.',j+1):= i.Supervisor.1]
  j = j + 1
}

> df
#    Employee Supervisor.1 Supervisor.2 Supervisor.3
# 1:     Bill          Jen          Amy        Steve
# 2:    James          Jen          Amy        Steve
# 3:      Amy        Steve           NA           NA
# 4:      Jen          Amy        Steve           NA
# 5:    Henry          Amy        Steve           NA
```

To reorder within rows:

```
df = cbind(df[, 1], t(apply(df[, -1], 1, function(r) c(rev(r[!is.na(r)]), r[is.na(r)]))))
> df
#    Employee    V1  V2  V3
# 1:     Bill Steve Amy Jen
# 2:    James Steve Amy Jen
# 3:      Amy Steve  NA  NA
# 4:      Jen Steve Amy  NA
# 5:    Henry Steve Amy  NA
```

Comment: "Steve" should be Supervisor.1 in all cases and the hierarchy should fall left to right. I am not familiar with data.table; can you quickly adjust the code to account for this criteria.

Comment: @DaleKube voila

Comment: This solution does not scale well. For example, if I'm using a data frame that contains 1,000 records of employee IDs and supervisor IDs, the output is a very wide data frame with 1,000 columns. There obviously aren't 1,000 hierarchical levels in an organization.

Comment: @DaleKube That's more likely caused by an irregularity in the hierarchy. can't say much else without seeing it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on the output, but want to work with the hierarchy, then data.tree is an excellent choice. Here are some examples:

```
libary(data.tree)
df <- data.frame("Employee"=c("Bill","James","Amy","Jen","Henry"),
                 "Supervisor"=c("Jen","Jen","Steve","Amy","Amy"))

dt <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)

#here's your org chart:

print(dt)
```

Let's find Jennas subordinates, together with their level in the hierarchy:

```
Get(FindNode(dt, 'Jen')$leaves, 'level')
```

This will return like so:

```
 Bill James 
    4     4
```

Just for fun, let's add personnel budgets:

```
dt$Set(salary = c(100000, 80000, 60000, 40000, 35000, 70000))
```

Print salary and cumulative salary

```
print(dt, 'salary', sal_subordinates = function(node) Aggregate(node, 'salary', sum))
```

This will print like this:

```
          levelName salary sal_subordinates
1 Steve             100000            80000
2  °--Amy            80000           130000
3      ¦--Jen        60000            75000
4      ¦   ¦--Bill   40000            40000
5      ¦   °--James  35000            35000
6      °--Henry      70000            70000
```

The data.tree [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) have many more examples of working with hierarchic data and aggregation.

Comment: Is there an easy way, using data.tree, to turn your last example back into a data frame format like mentioned above?